# I just want to bind label with the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, label

I want to show a data in sql database to a label, `razor MVC4`.

I have already created class

```
public class company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string discounttype { get; set; }
    public int discountrate { get; set; }
}
```

in .cshtml

`@html.labelfor (Model=>model.isim)`      // I actually don't know how to write this portion.

could you help?

Comment: I did not understand your question may clarify

Comment: I created a database table : company having name "name". I connected via  entity framework Model. how could I display name in label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enough to have a vision with the model you created and display the data in this way

```
@model company
@html.Label(Model.name)
```

and so for each property

Comment: ok but in the output only the table row is shown exp:  the output is : name     but I want to show the data keeped in the database. how?  e.g. name column has  john, michael,.....   I want to show  john as output.

Comment: I did not understand what you want (sorry my english sucks)

Comment: I want to print the value of sql data, not the column name., @model company
@html.LabelFor(x=> x.name) prints column name.

Comment: Sorry, replied quickly and ended up missing. See the updated code